# How to modify access to a class so that one particular attribute is only accessible by members of another class?

Tags: java, oop, encapsulation

Scenario, I have two classes Administrator and User. User contains  a boolean field entitled `Authorised`. I want an Administrator to be able to access and edit this field for any User but I don't want the user to have access to this field himself. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Java does not have a language construct for this. We'd have to implement the logic ourself.

Comment: If Administrator and User are hierarchically unrelated, then your only option at the language level is to put them in different packages, and give the field package access.  If they're in the same package, then the language solution is "don't write code in User to access the field".  Java access specifications are not a security boundary.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the best way or not. You could create an Entitled class that contains that entitled field which can only be set by an object of Administrator class. It's setter should accept an object of Administrator type, this will ensure that it cannot be set by any other object. User can have an object of this Entitled class as dependency. However, this is just too much work. I rather prefer @passer-by option.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a private method in the Administrator class.

```
private void authorized(User user) {
    user.authorized = true;

}
```

now only the administrator class can be used to call this method. But a user would still have access to the administrator class if it is imported into his environment.

does this work?